# Why my cell output become like this =SUM('J2':'J13')-SUM('AB2':'AB13')

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

this is my vba code:

```
Sub Macro1()

 Dim lastrow As Long

 lastrow = 13

     Range("AB" & CLng(lastrow) + 5).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(J2:J" & CLng(lastrow) & ")-SUM(AB2:AB" & CLng(lastrow) & ")"

End Sub
```

i wonder why the cell output have '' ?

Comment: use `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: Thank so muchh!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be.

```
Sub Macro1()

 Dim lastrow As Long

 lastrow = 13

     Range("AB" & CLng(lastrow) + 5).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(J2:J" & CLng(lastrow) & ")-SUM(AB2:AB" & CLng(lastrow) & ")"

End Sub
```